Having trouble with firewalld rich rule to drop MAC address on a system with Internal and NATed external interfaces
I have a linux box acting as router that has 2 interfaces running firewalld. One is "EXTERNAL" and is connected to the internet. The other is "TRUSTED" and connects to internal hosts. Computers on the internal network (10.x.x.x) reach the internet and are NAT'ed fine. They also reach each other fine.
When I create a rich rule to block a device by MAC addr, it works fine on the TRUSTED interface: the device cannot reach the internet, but it cannot reach any other host on the trusted network.
When I create the exact same rule for the EXTERNAL if, it's as if there is no rule. The target device can reach the internet and local hosts.
What am I doing wrong?  I want to block an internal device from reaching the internet, but not local machines. Here are the 2 rules:
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule source mac=90:b1:1c:99:41:1b drop"
firewall-cmd --zone=external --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule source mac=90:b1:1c:99:41:1b drop"

I have no idea what's the exact definition of "zone" in firewalld, but it sounds like what you want is that 90:b1:1c:99:41:1b can communicate with this firewall host but not hosts on "other networks" via the firewall host (note that normally that does NOT include hosts in the same L2 network since they can talk to each other directly). In iptables/nftables term that means you want to forbid "(L3) forward" traffics for this host but not "input" traffics.

It might work by having something like rule family=ipv4 source mac=90:b1:1c:99:41:1b destination not address=x.x.x.x drop (where x.x.x.x is the "TRUSTED IP" of the firewall host) for the TRUSTED zone (and don't mess with the EXTERNAL zone). Make sure you remove the added rule(s) first.

Thanks. The "Destination not address=" kinda works. Unfortunately, the "router" is also the host for DHCP and DNS and that traffic does need to reach it.

Does the MAC addr get NATed too? I assumed only TCP information was changed.

What do you mean by "the router"? Isn't the firewall host the "router" in concern? In that case you shouldn't have problem with DNS (unless you mean like LLMNR / mDNS). As for DHCP (and non-unicast DNS), you can probably add some corresponding accept rules (that match the corresponding destination port) before the drop rules.

MAC address does not get NATed, but stripped / replaced because the packet will be re-encapsulated with a new frame header when L3 forwarded out of an interface. The new source MAC address will be that of the interface. With that said, that is irrelevant to the MAC address match performed on traffics that traverse the forward chain. AFAIK the source MAC address available there would be the original one.

The reason that your rule for the "EXTERNAL zone" does not work might be because it does not introduce any "oif EXTERNAL_INTERFACE" nftables rule in any forward chain (i.e., the rule will only be matched against traffics that enter the system via the EXTERNAL_INTERFACE, but not those leave the system via it). You may check with nft list ruleset to see what exactly those firewalld rules "means".

Since the goal is to filter traffic between two zones try creating a policy: firewall-cmd --permanent --new-policy=mypolicy firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=mypolicy --set-target=ACCEPT firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=mypolicy --add-ingress-zone=trusted firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=mypolicy --add-egress-zone=external. Then add the rule to the policy firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=mypolicy --add-rich-rule='rule source mac="90:b1:1c:99:41:1b" drop' and reload firewall-cmd --reload. More details here https://firewalld.org/2020/09/policy-objects-introduction.

This policy works well. One interesting thing is that when I add the policy for the opposite direction, from external to trusted zones, I cannot create a rule for the destination mac address. You cannot add a rule with rule destination mac="90.... It fails with the error, Error: INVALID_RULE: attribute "mac" outside of any element. Seems oddly asymmetrical.  Looking at the documentation, the only elements listed are: service, port, protocol, masquerade, icmp-block, forward-port, and source-port There is no "source" by itself, but it clearly works for "mac"

I am glad it worked for you. source for mac is only available as rich rules which are extensions of the standard zone elements you listed (https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.richlanguage.html). There is no option to filter by destination mac because firewall rules take place before the routing decision.  Since the routing decision isn't done yet, the outgoing interface and thus destination mac address are not yet known, and thus can't be filtered on.
